# Platform Not Supported Exception

Tags: c#, windows-10

I'm developing a C# app and I want my app works on both Windows10 and Windows7.
To perform a Bluetooth scan I must use 2 different Libraries. One is for windows7 and the other is for Windows10.

I have made a verification code to detect if the app is running on Win10 or Win7.
After that I use the correct Libraries.

The problem is on windows7 My app crashes with a Platform Not Supported Exception.
This is because in my code there is a Win10 lib that is not supported, but this lib is not used in windows7 due to my verification code.
The Win10 lib is "Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement".

So, how can I do to avoid my app crashes.

This is a sample code (Not a working code just an example):

```
 using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;

 namespace ConsoleApp1
 {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         { 
             String System = "Windows7";
             if (System == "Windows7")
                 Console.WriteLine("Win7");
            else
             {
                 var watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
                 watcher.Received += Watcher_Received;
                 watcher.Start();
                 Console.WriteLine("Win10");
             }
         }

         private static void Watcher_Received(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender,
             BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Device detected");
         }


     }
 }
```

To use it add a refrence to Windows.winmd. You can find this file in the windows10 Dev Kit.

Comment: Post code as normal text (in code block format), not just a screenshot of your IDE.

Comment: Hi @A.Le Floch, Welcome to SO. Please add the actual code to your post (not an image of it). In that way you are more likely to get answers.

Comment: You need to post the actual code you are working with that causes the error and point to which line when debugging crashes the app.  You will probably also need to include how you are loading the libraries in your project as your example does not show that as well.  There is too much guessing here to accurately help you.

Comment: This is the code. Try it and you'll see. It crashes.